# Where to handle user's input data in DialogPreference inherited class?

Tags: android

I  have custom `DialogPreference` of two `EditText` views and do comparison of those in `onDialogClosed()` which doesn't work for me because in case `strings` are not equal I can not stop `dialog` closure, so I need the method before `onDialogClosed()` to make these comparisons and then decide whether to call `onDialogClosed()` or not.

So, any other good place to make comparisons or ability to cancel dialog closure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `TextWatcher` implementation to the edittext and in its `afterTextChanged()` callback do the comparison of strings. If the strings match enable the `OK` button, else disable it.

```
ed2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (ed1.gettext().tostring().compareIgnoreCase(s.tostring()) == 0) {
             // enable the ok button.
        } else {
             // disable it.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can I get access to `Button` instance of `DialogPreference` class?

Comment: Im afraid you'll have to do a custom preference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I use [onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) to achieve something similar to this.

Comment: How can you do data comparison of elements in `dialog` and prevent it from closure using this method?

Comment: I don't prevent it from closing, I check to see if the user has closed it here via the button on the dialog and if they haven't I'll redisplay the dialog. It works quite well.

Comment: Cool, please let me know how to redisplay it and I'm fine.

Comment: Simply show the dialog again in onDismiss, it looks like it never disappears then, on most devices, except in the case where the user holds the hard menu key.

Comment: Mine is extended from 'DialogPreferences' and I do not show it programmatically. Can you show peace of code how you `show` it?